# How do I only show UIToolBar when virtual keyboard is present

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

The toolbar gets shown even when using a hardware keyboard. This is the code I'm using to add the toolbar. I'm running this code in viewWillAppear.

```
 UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"Close") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(closeKeyboard)],
                           nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    self.mobileNumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter to identify if the keyboard shows or hides. Add the following lines on viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

and implement the methods to do your actions:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
```

I hope it helps.